# subfolder based on date format using powershell

Tags: powershell-4.0

We have main folder `c:\backup` under the location below subfolders are generated on this date format which contains the daily backup of the application 28-05-2020. We need to compress the folder daily to save the space. For example, Powershell should select the daily date folder from 28-05-2020 and compress it and move it. Tomorrow another backup folder will get generated like 29-05-2020 etc. How to compress it based on the updated time using the loop.

```
foreach($directory in $source1) {
     $compress = Compress-Archive $directory -DestinationPath $path\$Date.zip
}
```